# タグシノニムの提案： go ← golang

Tags: 討議, タグ, タグの別名の提案

Go言語を指すタグとして、現在 [go](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go) と [golang](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/golang) の二つが存在しています。

後者を使っている投稿は3件しかありませんが、他所のサイトで golang という表記も依然見かける（ような気がする）ので、これを機にシノニムを設定してしまってもよいかと思います。

なお英語版でも [go](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go) をマスターとしてタグシノニムが[設定されています](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/go/synonyms)。

シノニム作成への反対意見や、逆に [golang](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/golang) をマスターとした方がいい、という意見がありましたらお寄せください。数日待って問題なさそうであれば設定しようかと思います。

Comment: "タグシノニムの提案"って議題を出さずとも出来て投票制になってますよね？それをしない理由って何かあるのでしょうか？タグシノニムってモデレーター以外あまり編集されていないようですが、もしかしてモデレーターだと投票せず即時反映出来たり……？、、、議題自体は編集に賛成です。

Comment: @Myaku はい、他の投票系と同じく、モデレーターだと即時反映になってしまいます。（こっちに書いた方がコメントもできますし、シノニム提案よりは目立つので、意見を集めるにはいいかなというのもあります）

Comment: といいつつ、改めて確認したらシノニムの提案はモデレーターでもできました（提案と作成は別機能でどっちも使える）。それでも目立ちにくいのは確かですが...。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

シノニムの作成とタグのマージを行いました。